# How to Row merge in RDLC as Crystal Reports

Tags: .net, .net-core, crystal-reports, rdlc

I have crystal reports that I can merge as excel. Now a days I need to develop same report in rdlc. But in terms of merging rows I cannot do it as excel. I know that I can do that using group. But I want to merge without group or sum. Here is the picture of crystal and rdlc. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.
**Crystal Report**
[image]

**RDLC Report**

[image]